# remove element li depending on value of input element inside li JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with `li`'s

```
<li><label><input type='checkbox' class='className'  value='" + someID + "' /> Some Name </label></li>
```

The way I create `li`'s

```
var container= "#checkbox-menu"
var tempElement ="<li><label><input type='checkbox' class='className'  value='" + someID + "' /> Some Name </label></li>";
$(container).append(tempElement);
```

I need to delete `li` element where value in `input` is equal to `someID`.

I came up with something like this

```
$("#checkbox-menu li:has('label'):has(input[value='"+ someID +"'])").remove()
```

But it didnt work.

Thank You for help in advance.

Comment: The value in your <li> is `someID`, what you're removing is `someOtherId`.

Comment: My bad, `someId` and `someOtherId` are the same things. I will edit to not confuse.

Comment: where is your id, is in li?

Comment: Please show us the entire construction of the `li`.  It looks like you are dynamically creating them.

Comment: I do dynamically create them, true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i've got the wrong end of what you're after but it seems like you just want to use this line to remove the li within the function:

```
$('input[value="' + someID + '"]').parents('li').remove();
```